# LAG is working on first row only. ignores all the other following rows

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 (Standard). It appears the LAG function works on the first row only.

My raw data is as follows (in a table variable)

`select BatchId, [Day], Change, Opening, Closing from @Data`

[image: Data before LAG]

but this query only works on my query on the first row only

```
SELECT  
BatchId,
[Day], 
LAG(Closing, 1, 500) OVER (PARTITION BY BatchId ORDER BY [Day] asc) as Opening,
Change,
(LAG(Closing, 1, 500) OVER (PARTITION BY BatchId ORDER BY [Day] asc) - Change) as Closing
FROM @Data
order by [Day] asc
```

which results in the following:

[image: Only row 1 has valid values]

Closing is basically (Opening - Change). I seem to missing something simple because every example I've seen looks the same

Comment: It seems to be working correctly to me. Every row has a value of 0, so `0` is the correct value when you want to **prior row's** value for `Closing`. I don't think what you want is `LAG` but a cumulative `SUM`. **Consumable** sample data, and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: My assumption is the lag operation works row by row as data is populated into the result set. Is that correct versus it only working on the data already in the table before the query is run? that is, it doesn't work dynamically?

Comment: `LAG` returns the value of the column from the prior row. All your rows have the value `0` in your sample data, as I mention, so the prior row will always be `0`.

Comment: Again though, if you provide **consumable** sample data (not an image) and the results you are expecting we can show you how to achieve what you are after.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for the cumulative sum idea. I have posted my new implementation below and all seems to be fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Larnu's comment for pointing me in the right direction, I went for a select with a cumulative sum, as follows:

```
select BatchId, [Day], Change,
    500 - (sum(Change) OVER (ORDER BY [Day] asc) - Change) as Opening,
    sum(Change) OVER (ORDER BY [Day] asc) as CumChange, 
    500 - sum(Change) OVER (ORDER BY [Day] asc) as Closing  
from
@Data
group by BatchId, [Day], Change
```

500 is just the initial opening amount

And my result is now as follows:

[image]

Comment: `ORDER BY [Day] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` otherwise you will get incorrect results if there are multiple rows with the same day, it's also better for performance